# getting error :'module' object has no attribute 'connect_to_region' for boto on python

Tags: python, boto

I am learning how to use the boto module with python and AWS
when i am trying to run the follow code:

```
import boto.ses
conn = boto.ses.connect_to_region("us-west-2")
```

I keep geting the follow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Document/PycharmProjects/Boto/boto_ses.py", line 4, in <module>
conn = boto.ses.connect_to_region("us-west-2")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect_to_region'
```

I am subscribed to the AWS service,
I am using the pycharm as an IDE and have the boto.cfg file configured correctly

Comment: works for me.  I suspect improper installation of `boto`.

Answer (score 1):

From this line of the traceback:

```
File "D:/Document/PycharmProjects/Boto/boto_ses.py", line 4, in <module>
```

You apparently haven't actually installed `boto`, you've just copied its source code into your project. That's now how you use packages in Python.

See [Installing Python Modules](http://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html) in the Python docs, [Installing Boto](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/getting_started.html) in the Boto docs, and [Quickstart](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) in the `pip` docs.

Or… I believe PyCharm has built-in GUI functionality for managing your installed site-packages, and building virtual environments and managing *their* installed packages, so you don't even have to learn how to use `pip` or `setup.py` files if you don't want to.

Comment: hi abarnet, I did install boto , in fact it is working with other models of the Amazon Web Services (AWS) like SES (simple email service). i am also not able to run this command and geting the same error when i am running it directly from the python interpeter.

Comment: Then either (a) you've installed it, and _also_ copied it into your project, which means there's essentially a 50/50 chance any given module will work, or (b) you've installed it, and _also_ created a local package and module with the same name, which will overshadow the one in your site-packages. Either way, the problem is the same: there should not be a file named `Boto/boto_ses.py` inside your project directory.

Comment: hi again,i reinstall the boto module on pycharm ,now it is the most upgraded one with version 2.14.0 i also refactor the name of the file boto_ses to boto_ses1 but i am getting the same error.

Comment: @FirdaNovo: You're telling me that you no longer have a file named `D:/Document/PycharmProjects/Boto/boto_ses.py`, but you still get the exact same error, with the same reference to that file? If so, that is possible in some circumstances if there's a leftover .pyc file for the no-longer-there .py file.

Comment: after changing the file name it was solved,thank you for the help